# Maven Child pom custom properties

Tags: maven

I have a parent pom with a lot of child pom files.
Child pom have custom properties that I need to set before building a specific module, and I would like maven to build all its dependent modules.

For example Parent A has modules B, C and D. Module B is dependent on modules C and D. Module B has customer properties for versions of C and D. However when building B, I would like to know how to specify the custom properties value of C and D so that maven build C and D with that value before building B.

Let say I want to B to have version 2.0.0, and  C and D to be version 2.0.0, but versions 2.0.0 for C and D don't exist in repo, I want maven to build C version 2.0.0 and D version 2.0.0 before building B version 2.0.0, then build B version 2.0.0

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>example</groupId>
  <artifactId>module-B</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0</version>

  <properties>
        <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <moduleC.version>1.0.0</moduleC.version>
        <moduleD.version>1.0.0</moduleD.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>moduleC</groupId>
      <artifactId>moduleC</artifactId>
      <version>${moduleC.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>moduleD</groupId>
      <artifactId>moduleD</artifactId>
      <version>${moduleD.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    </project>
```

Comment: The structure and the exact question remain unclear. Maven builds the modules in the correct order so that if X depends on Y, then Y is build first.

Comment: Module B depends on Modules C and D. I want to build module B with version 2.0.0 by doing that I want maven to build C and D with version 2.0.0. Module B has two properties to refer to modules C and B versions to use.

Comment: Provide some example POM files and it might be easier for others to understand your exact problem and consequently provide solid answers.

Comment: <artifactId>module-B</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
  <properties>
    <revision>1.0.0</revision>
    <moduleC.version>1.0.0</moduleC.version>
    <moduleD.version>1.0.0</moduleD.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>moduleC</groupId>
      <artifactId>moduleC</artifactId>
      <version>${moduleC.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>moduleD</groupId>
      <artifactId>moduleD</artifactId>
      <version>${moduleD.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

Comment: The pom above has version 1.0.0 for Module B, C and D. I want to build module B with version 2.0.0 and modules C and D with version 2.0.0 but, version 2.0.0 does not exist yet for modules C and D. I want maven to build version 2.0.0 for modules C and D, before building module B.

Comment: Please _edit_ the question instead of pasting unreadable XML into the comment section.

Comment: hm maybe your want to to read something about the [maven reactor](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) and if I understand you'r question: if you want to automatically build all of these modules , use a pom project as an aggregator and include b,c,d as module projects. furthermore I would use the project.version instead of explicitly defining  the versions for c and d